# React-Redux not dispatching action type

Tags: reactjs, redux, action, dispatch

Here is react/redux application.
This a basic stripped down version of what I am trying to accomplish. showFolder() produces a list of folders and a button to click where it calls the removeFolder action from FolderActions.js. The button works and will call the function in FolderActions.js however will not dispatch the type. The functions works as I can see the console.log message but will not dispatch the type using redux..

I have a strong feeling it's the way I'm calling the function however I am lost at the moment

```
import {
  addFolder,
  getFolder,
  removeFolder,

} from "../../../actions/FolderActions";

class Folders extends Component {

  onRemoveFolder = (e,id) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(id);
    this.props.removeFolder(id);
  };

  showFolders = () => {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.folder.map((key, index) => (          
            <form onSubmit={(e) => this.onRemoveFolder(e,key._id)}>
              <input type="submit"></input>
            </form>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  };

  render() {
    let { isShown } = this.state;
    return (
         <div>
          <div className="folder_names">{this.showFolders()}</div>
        </div> 
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    userId: state.auth.user._id,
    folder: state.folder.data
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {removeFolder,addFolder,getFolder})(
  Folders
);
```

**FolderActions.js**

```
export const removeFolder = id => dispatch => {
  console.log("called")
  axios
    .delete(`api/folders/${id}`)
    .then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: DELETE_FOLDER,
        payload: id
      })
    )
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

Comment: Have you add the `redux-thunk` middleware?

Comment: @MarkoCen, yeah, I have two other actions running in this component that are working fine

Comment: Try adding async await if it is asynchronous

Comment: @jackstride The code looks ok and should work, are you sure `console.log(err)` doesn't log anything?

Comment: @GhazanfarKhan Made no difference

Comment: @Clarity No errors are logging, it seems the whole function is ignoring dispatch

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but my server never sent a response.

Because the server never sent a response, when I made a request, res is not true so cannot dispatch the type and payload.

Sorry for wasting peoples time!

Answer (score 1):

Your function call looks strange to me...

Can you try defining a proper `mapDispatchToProps` and calling `dispatch` within that instead of within your function?

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  removeFolder: (id) => dispatch( removeFolder(id) ),
  addFolder: (id) => dispatch( addFolder(id) ),
  getFolder: (id) => dispatch( getFolder(id) ),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
  Folders
);
```

```js
export const removeFolder = id => {
  // code block
};
```

I know that's more a rework that you probably were hoping for, but does it work?

Comment: Forgot to mention I have this commented out on my version and didn't work. I want to say it's an issue with using .then after axios.delete? Removing .then and .catch I can see the action type is being sent..